# Passing an array() instead of object gives: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, arrays, object

Using PHP 5.3.3 and Drupal 7.17 I've created a short custom PHP script, in which I'd like to call Drupal's function - which in turn expects an object having a `pass` property:

```
function user_check_password($password, $account) {
  if (substr($account->pass, 0, 2) == 'U$') {
    $stored_hash = substr($account->pass, 1);
    $password = md5($password);
  }
  .....
}
```

So in my script I try to create such an object "on the fly":

```
<?php

require_once('/path/to/drupal/includes/password.inc');
........
$sth = $db->prepare(SQL);
$sth->execute(array($username));
if ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if (user_check_password($password, array('pass' => $row['pass']))) {
                header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
                print json_encode($row);
        }
}
```

However this gives me an error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Which probably means: PHP doesn't accept my array, it wants an object there.

How could I create an anonymous object "on the fly" then to make it happy?

Comment: Change `$account->pass` to `$account['pass']`. It is the way to access to an array key.

Comment: Bad suggestion, because I don't want to modify Drupal's `includes/password.inc` file. I just want to use that function from my small script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting an error, because `Array` is not an `Object`.  If you don't want to manually create an object (as in the answer by @adityamenon), then you can simply cast your array to object:

```
user_check_password($password, (object)array('pass' => $row['pass']))
```

Answer (score 3):

To make new 'anonymous' objects, use stdClass.

`$new_object = new stdClass;`

In your code:

```
<?php

require_once('/path/to/drupal/includes/password.inc');
........
$sth = $db->prepare(SQL);
$sth->execute(array($username));
if ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$new_object = new stdClass;
$new_object->pass = $row['pass'];
        if (user_check_password($password, $new_object)) {
                header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
                print json_encode($row);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to pass it to the function in the same row? Smth. like `user_check_password($password, ...create obj here...)`

Comment: I updated my answer with a vanilla type code example, but you can look at [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in PHP if you want to be cool ;)